# Determine the area of the intersection of two rectangles

Tags: c++, intersection

I have two rectangles, each identified by a set of four coordinates. I've read up on how to see whether they intersect, but how can I calculate the area of the intersection? The rectangles are not axis-aligned.

Is there an OpenCV function for this? I was told there was, but I fail to find it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Treat your rectangles as general polygons, and decompose the problem into two steps:

- compute the intersection of the two polygons, which itself is a polygon (or is empty);
- compute the area of the resulting polygon.

There's plenty of literature on the Web for both problems.

I don't know anything about OpenCV so can't give any advice there.

Comment: even better - treat them as convex polygons

Answer (score 1):

You can easily convert the Qt libraries code for that in order to be used with OpenCV.

Look for this function:

```
QRect QRect::operator&(const QRect &r) const
```

In [qrect.cpp](http://qt.gitorious.org/qt/qt/blobs/4.7/src/corelib/tools/qrect.cpp).